# How to convert NSString HTML markup to plain text NSString?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, nsstring

Been searching the net for an example of how to convert HTML string markup into Plain text.

I get my information from a feed which contains `HTML`, I then display this information in a Text View. does the `UITextView` have a property to convert `HTML` or do I have to do it in code. I tried:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCString:self.fullText encoding:NSUTF8StringEndcoding];
```

but doesn't seem to work. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do it by parsing the html by using NSScanner class

```
- (NSString *)flattenHTML:(NSString *)html {

    NSScanner *theScanner;
    NSString *text = nil;
    theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];

    while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL] ; 

        [theScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&text] ;

        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text] withString:@""];
    }
    //
    html = [html stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    return html;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't deal with single quotes but for everything else works fine.

Comment: If you are having single quotes and you don't want to show them just replace there occurrence by blank string

Comment: Hi @Madhup. please have look at the question -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148291/convert-formatted-html-text-string-to-nsstring-parts and advice.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using UIWebView then it will be easier to parse HTML to text:

```
fullArticle = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.getElementsByTagName('article')[0].innerText;"]; // extract the contents by tag

fullArticle = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerText"]; // extract text inside body part of HTML
```

Answer (score -1):

you can't do it directly i guess.. however you can use NSXML Parser and parse the HTML and retrieve exactly what you want...

Comment: would this method keep the formatting? What I want is to display the formatted HTML in plain text, so keep links, <h1> <p> etc.. how do other app do this?

Comment: NSXML parser will not parse normal HTML.  It fails on HTML only characters.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to present the text in read-only fashion, why not use UIWebView?

Comment: UIWebView display's a webpage inside a app? need a control or method of keeping the html format but not displaying it. my output contains the markup were i want to it keep to style but not show the html.