# Convert formatted HTML text string to NSString parts

Tags: iphone, html, decode

I want to decode HTML string and store it in NSString.

following is the html string for one of the response from google direction api.

```
teststring is Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>Kennington Park Rd/A3</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Continue to follow A3</div><div style="font-size:0.9em">Entering toll zone in 1.7&nbsp;km at Newington Causeway/A3</div><div style="font-size:0.9em">Go through 2 roundabouts</div>
```

I want to store this html string in Array of 4 different NSStrings with following 4 NSStrings (removing all information for size colour)

```
Turn right onto Kennington Park Rd/A3
Continue to follow A3
Entering toll zone in 1.7 km at Newington Causeway/A3
Go through 2 roundabouts
```

I have used following method to convert html string to plain text.(html_response is the response from server and stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText is the method defined in custom class file)

```
testString = (NSString*) [html_response stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];
NSLog(@"%@",testString);
```

but it converts whole string instead of breaking it in parts.
output at the console is

```
Turn right onto Kennington Park Rd/A3Continue to follow A3 Entering toll zone in 1.7 km at Newington Causeway/A3 Go through 2 roundabouts
```

So do I need to write custom method to do this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a very nice NSString [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/Category.html) that you can use, it's a part of the project [MWFeedParser](https://github.com/renegade78/MWFeedParser/). More specifically, you look for the file [NSString+HTML](https://github.com/renegade78/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.h).

The NSString+HTML category adds the following methods to the NSString Class,

```
- (NSString *)stringByStrippingTags;
- (NSString *)stringWithNewLinesAsBRs;
- (NSString *)stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace;
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities;
```

You could then try something like:

```
NSString *summary = [[[htmlString stringByStrippingTags] stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace] stringByDecodingHTMLEntities];
```

Hope it helps!, good luck :)

Comment: thanks for your answer. by the method you suggested, I have html string is converted to nsstring but I need to store it as an array containing 4 different nsstring. Do you any idea how can I do it? Do I neeed to override above methods?