# Convert this Html text in simple text in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

```
&lt;strong&gt;Occupant Safety&lt;/strong&gt;
```

All ILX models come standard with dual front, front side and full-length side curtain airbags in addition to traction and stability control systems and electronic brakeforce distribution.

```
&lt;strong&gt;Key competitors&lt;/strong&gt;
```

As the new entry-level offering from Acura, the ILX will compete with the Buick Verano and the Audi A3. Buyers can also consider cross-shopping it against Acura's own TSX, which is a size larger yet only marginally more expensive.

**Please say how to convert this html tags in simple text in iphone**

Comment: u have to use UIWebView ??

Comment: yes i used that but it is not converted

Answer (score 2):

try this..
https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser

Import the Category folder.

Define only..

## import "NSString+HTML.h"

And write like this...

simpletxt.text = [YourHTMLString stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the html tags in the string, you have some `NSString` categories to get it worked, follow this

[Convert formatted HTML text string to NSString parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148291/convert-formatted-html-text-string-to-nsstring-parts)

In the accepted answer you can find your solution, how to escape html tags in the string.