# How to convert html string to normal string in iOS?

Tags: html, ios, nsstring

I am going to ask a simple and basic question, don't kill me for this.

I want to decode HTML string into normal string.

I have tried:

```
 NSString*  testString =[htmlString  stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];
 - (NSString *)stringByStrippingTags;
 - (NSString *)stringWithNewLinesAsBRs;
 - (NSString *)stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace;
 - (NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;
 - (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities;
```

but none of these are in work now. so Help me to remove " ’ " and " &#8211 " etc and convert html to normal string.

Comment: Do you mean that you're using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148291/convert-formatted-html-text-string-to-nsstring-parts? Because we don't know what do your methods. So we can't guess what's the issue. Did you need something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757655/how-to-remove-html-tags-from-nsstring-in-iphone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757655/how-to-remove-html-tags-from-nsstring-in-iphone In this question when I add code-  [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

It is adding some more line like:
 NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7faab2dca0f0> font-family: \"Times New Roman\"; font-weight: normal; font-style:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148291/convert-formatted-html-text-string-to-nsstring-parts I have used this answer but its not working

Comment: If tou used my code, you need to use the "finalString" using `string` method of NsAttributefString

Comment: ohk It's working but i'll let you know it if there is any issue

Answer (score -1):

Try this code..

- (NSString *)stringByStrippingHTML:(NSString *)inputString
  {
  NSMutableString *outString;

  if (inputString)
  {
      if ([inputString length] > 0)
      {
          NSRange r;

  ```
      inputString = [inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</div>" withString:@"\n\n"];
      inputString = [inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</DIV>" withString:@"\n\n"];
      inputString = [inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br/>" withString:@"\n"];
      inputString = [inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br />" withString:@"\n"];
      inputString = [inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br>" withString:@"\n"];
      inputString = [inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<BR>" withString:@"\n"];
      inputString = [inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<BR />" withString:@"\n"];
      inputString = [inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<BR/>" withString:@"\n"];

      outString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:inputString];
      while ((r = [outString rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
      {
          [outString deleteCharactersInRange:r];
      }
      NSString *finalString = outString;
      finalString =[finalString stringByDecodingHTMLEntities];
      return finalString;
  }
  ```

  }
  return outString;
  }