# How to convert Html tags to plain text in iPhone

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have webservice response like this.

```
NSString *str= @"Slight <b>left</b> onto <b>Adelaide Rd/B509</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Continue to follow Adelaide Rd</div>";
```

I have to convert html tags in the above str to plain text.Can u please suggest me
solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class to parse the HTML.

Have a look at this post:
[How to convert NSString HTML markup to plain text NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606134/iphone-xcode-how-to-convert-nsstring-html-markup-to-plain-text-nsstring)