# How to parse HTML to PlainText while maintaining paragraph formatting

Tags: iphone, ios, html-parsing, libxml2, nsscanner

I have an iOS app that is pulling data from a Restful web service. A portion of the content I am receiving is being loaded into a `UITextView`.  The portion that will be going into the text view is coming in as HTML format.  I need to convert it from HTML to plain text while using the paragraph tags to format the text view properly.

Here is what the HTML format looks like

```
<p data-seq="1"><span class="paragraph">Content of paragraph 1</span></p><p data-seq="2"><span class="paragraph">Content of paragraph 2</span></p>
```

You can see that `<p data-seq="2"><span class="paragraph">....</span></p>` designates the start and end of the paragraph.

I initially tried using `NSScanner` from this example, [How to convert NSString HTML markup to plain text NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606134/iphone-xcode-how-to-convert-nsstring-html-markup-to-plain-text-nsstring).  This was quick to implement but it strips all tags and and parses the text as one long paragraph.

I have added `libXml2` to my code.  I started following this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios) for implementation but after I started working through it I wasn't sure how to format the output into paragraphs.

I have also seen recommendations for the [DTCoreText library](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) but I didn't see a lot of info on it.

Could someone possibly throw up a snippet using any of the above three options or one of their own on how to parse html into plain text while maintaining the paragraphs?

***SOLUTION***

Per lxt's recommendation I investigated `DTCoreText`.  Once I managed to get it installed in my app (definitely recommend cocoa pods for that). It was easy as `#import "DTCoreText.h"` in my `detailViewController` and then the lines below to add it to the `UITextView`.

```
    NSDictionary *options = @{DTUseiOS6Attributes: [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]};
    NSData *htmlData = [self.htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSAttributedString *stringArticle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData options:options documentAttributes:NULL];
    self.newsDetailText.attributedText = stringArticle;
```

The first build failed because I didn't include the `DTUseiOS6Attributes` line.  The second build succeeded and the detail view was perfectly formatted.  It was a fist pump moment!  Thanks again for the recommendation lxt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would honestly recommend using `DTCoreText` rather than writing your own parser. There's no real benefit reinventing the wheel, and it's also a widely used library with a large user base.

I am surprised you had trouble finding info about it, the library [has very good documentation available](https://docs.cocoanetics.com/DTCoreText/), and the author is also pretty active on Twitter ([@cocoanetics](https://twitter.com/Cocoanetics)).

You can use the nifty `DTAttributedTextView` class provided in place of your `UITextView`. The library also provides a category that extends `NSAttributedString` with a `initWithHTMLData:documentAttributes:` method. This will let you create your attributed string and plug it into your view. It's really no more than a couple of lines of code.

Comment: lxt, thanks for the response.  I should have said "I didn't study much info on `DTCoreText` parser.  I glanced at it on github and saw one snippet about the `NSAttributedString`.  I will read up on the documentation and the method you recommended to see if I can figure out how to make it work.